# Вывод данных из базы в зависимости от значения одного из столбцов

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Есть база данных из 4 столбцов.

```
COLUMN_ID = "_id";
COLUMN_NUMBER = "Number";
COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
COLUMN_CHECK = "Checkbox";
```

Вывожу в ListView данные из неизменяемых столбцов

```
COLUMN_NUMBER = "Number";
COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
```

Столбец `COLUMN_CHECK = "Checkbox";` имеет значение `0` или `1`
Как мне отфильтровать значение выводимых столбцов в зависимости от этого значения и выводить только те строки, в которых это значение `1`?

Вот код:

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            db = sqlHelper.open();
            userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
            String[] headers = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NUMBER};
            userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                    userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);

            userAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                @Override
                public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                        return db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
                    }
                    else {
                        return db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE +
                                        " where " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + " like ?" +
                                        " or " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NUMBER + " like ?",
                                new String[]{"%" + constraint.toString() + "%", "%" + constraint.toString() + "%"});
                    }
                }
            });

            userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + " where " + COLUMN_CHECK + " = 1"
```

Comment: не могу сообразить, в какое именно место вставить? Попробовал во все - не работает

Comment: @ru38irk Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: Понимаю, что Ваш ответ логичен, но не фильтрует. Вот и думаю, во все ли места этот фильтр поставить или только в определенное?

Comment: @ru38irk Вы хотите сказать, что такой запрос возвращает записи, в которых `Checkbox` не равно `1`?

Comment: у меня в ListView попадают все строки, независимо от того, `1` там или `0`, вот я и думаю, куда поставить Ваш код - в конкретную строку моего кода или во все?

Comment: @ru38irk Вы не перекомпилировали код. То есть запускаете Вы не тот код, который мы обсуждаем.

Comment: Вы подскажите, куда его в моем коде подставить?))

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался!